# Bulkuser creation in AD using powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to upload bulk users to my AD using the code below.
But it keep giving me an error.

```
import-csv C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\properties1.csv |ForEach-Object {New-ADUser -path "OU=Users,OU=ICTLAB,DC=gdgshj,DC=com" -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -SamAccountName $_.SamAccountName -GivenName $_.GivenName -Name $_.Name -DisplayName $_.DisplayName -profilepath $_.Profilepath Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $_.Password -Force) Enable-ADAccount -Identity $_.SamAccountName }
```

The error is as attached.

[image: Error in powershell]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a statement terminator for the `New-ADUser` cmdlet, before calling `Set-ADAccountPassword`.

You can either use `;`, or place `Set-ADAccountPassword` on a separate line:

```
Import-Csv C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\properties1.csv |ForEach-Object {
    New-ADUser -path "OU=Users,OU=ICTLAB,DC=gdgshj,DC=com" -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -SamAccountName $_.SamAccountName -GivenName $_.GivenName -Name $_.Name -DisplayName $_.DisplayName -profilepath $_.Profilepath 
    Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $_.Password -Force) 
    Enable-ADAccount -Identity $_.SamAccountName 
}
```

You can also chain the commands together in a single pipeline, if you use the `-PassThru` switch on `New-ADUser` and `Set-ADAccountPassword` (notice the `|` at the end of each line):

```
Import-Csv C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\properties1.csv |ForEach-Object {
    New-ADUser -path "OU=Users,OU=ICTLAB,DC=gdgshj,DC=com" -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -SamAccountName $_.SamAccountName -GivenName $_.GivenName -Name $_.Name -DisplayName $_.DisplayName -profilepath $_.Profilepath -PassThru |
    Set-ADAccountPassword -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $_.Password -Force) -PassThru | 
    Enable-ADAccount
}
```

Comment: I also need to add the domain name after the USER LOGON NAME '@gdgshj.com' I would also like to Enable, PASSWORD NEVER EXPIRES and USER CANNOT CHANGE PASSWORD options under the account tab. How do I add those codes to this powershell script.